# How to create Linkbutton in Drupal 7

Tags: button, drupal-7

I stuck with adding LinkButton inside Drupal. The Linkbutton similar like this:-

```
<form action="http://google.com/" method="get">

<button style="width:200px;height:40px; background:#4788CC;color:white;font face:verdana">
 ADD THINGS
</button>

</form>
```

I want to create LinkButton using Drupal API same as HTML mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at drupal's Form API:

You can try something like this:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu().
 */
function moduleName_menu(){
 $items = array();
 $items['url'] = array(
   'title' => 'Test',
   'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
   'page arguments' => array('my_form'),
   'access arguments' => array('access content'),
 );

 return $items;
}

function my_form(){
  $form = array();
  $form['my_field'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Go'),
  );

  return $form;
}

function my_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
    $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
    $form_state['redirect'] = 'custom url';
}
```

Comment: It will result into a link because '#type' => 'link', but I need a link button which would display like button but link to some other page within the site. Please suggest.

Comment: You can style the link from css to look like a button... or try the new code i changed it to a submit button